# How to get a list of fields in a unique constraint

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a table with a unique constraint on one or more fields. Given the constraint name, I want to query the system views to get the list of fields that are part of this constraint.

SQL Server 2005.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at information_schema.constraint_column_usage

```
select column_name from information_schema.constraint_column_usage
where constraint_name = 'your constraint'
```